# JavaScript で特定のタグで挟まれた文字列を変更したい

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptで、あるH3タグの中の文字列を変えたいのですがどうすれば良いでしょうか？

```html
<h3 id = "test><font color ="red">ここの文字を変えたい。</font></h3>
```

Comment: 「<h3 id-"test">ここ</h3>」の場合はどうしたいですか? 「<h3 id-"test"><font color="blue">ここ</font></h3>」の場合は? 「<h3 id-"test"><font color="blue"><b>ここ</b></font></h3>」の場合は?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="<font color='red'>newtext</font>";
```

もしfontラベルにもIDを追加したら、

```
<h3 id="test"><font id="test2" color ="red">ここの文字を変えたい。</font></h3>
```

以下の通り：

```
document.getElementById("test2").textContent="newtext";
```